# how do i load json file names (without extension) into a listbox and into a combobox (python)?

Tags: python, json, tkinter, listbox

I need to import json files from a folder as items in a listbox and then a combobox.  I try loading the files to the list box with this:

```
path_to_json = './'
json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path_to_json) if pos_json.endswith('.json')]
self.profiles_print(json_files)
```

i can load the files into the list box, but they all load on one line as 1 item.

How can i make it individual items?

Thanks,
Dom

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is? Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

answered from other source:

```
path_to_json = './'
    json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path_to_json) if pos_json.endswith('.json')]
    for i in json_files:
        self.profiles_print(i)
```